# What unit of measurement are they using for altitude?

Tags: lost-in-space, lost-in-space-2018

Right in the beginning of Episode 1 of *Lost in Space* (2018), the ship is knocked off course and rapidly loses altitude. The computer voice announces the decreasing altitude as "4,000 feet", then "3,000 feet", and then 2,000 feet. However, the display console is shown when they hit 3,000 feet, and the letter next to the number is "m", which would typically stand for "meters" or "miles" in a measurement of distance.

[image: Screenshot of clip from the show, where the display console reads "3,004m"]

Thus, the visual measurement seems to contradict the auditory measurement.

How can this discrepancy be resolved?

Comment: Since it is altitude "m" means meters, not miles ! Clearly, the plane is european, the commentary is US, and nobody cared to convert the units.

Answer (score 8):

It can’t.  This is a continuity error.  The makers either didn’t know, or didn’t care.